# How to implement iterator end()

Tags: c++, class, iterator

I wrote an implementation for iterator++ reaching the end of the tree :

```
   // If we finished the stack and didn't fine any unvisited file, we're done
    if( m_stack.empty() )
    {
        // Set the iterator to point to the end of the tree
        m_pFile = NULL;
        m_currentIndex = 0;
        endFlag = true;
        return *this;
    }
}
```

How should I implement end() function for the class using this iterator

Thanks.

Comment: There's not enough context to know what you're asking. Where is this code? inside your iterator's `operator++`? If reaching the end sets those variables then the `end()` function should return an iterator with those values set.

Comment: Let me make sure I understand this question. You want to know how you should implement end() function for a class whose definition, and declaration, you don't think is necessary to show, except for not even the entire ++ operator, but some portion of it?